# Removing DataGrid cell dotted border?

Tags: wpf, datagrid, border

[image]

I want to remove the dotted border around Romance that can be seen in the above datagridcell. The border appears whenever i use the key board left-right navigation keys. How can i get rid of it ?

Answer (score 6):

You have to clear out the `FocusVisualStyle` of the DataGridCells.

```
<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
            <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.CellStyle>
...
```